# DB2 SQL Syntax on inner join with subquery

Tags: sql, db2, subquery, inner-join

I am getting "TDEST.ENDZONE is not valid in the context where it is used".

```
    select * from LYNX.LEGSUM T2 inner join
(    SELECT
      TLORDER.END_ZONE,LEGSUM.LS_DRIVER, LEGSUM.LS_POWER_UNIT
    FROM
      LYNX.LEGSUM LEGSUM
      LEFT OUTER JOIN LYNX.TLORDER TLORDER ON LEGSUM.LS_DLID = TLORDER.DETAIL_LINE_ID
    WHERE
      TLORDER.ORIGIN = 'PRO8060'
      AND LEGSUM.LS_ACTUAL_DATE >= '2017-01-01 00:00:00'
      AND LEGSUM.LS_ACTUAL_DATE < '2018-01-01 00:00:00'
      AND NOT (
        TLORDER.CURRENT_STATUS = 'CANCEL'
        OR TLORDER.CURRENT_STATUS = 'CANCL'
        OR TLORDER.CURRENT_STATUS = 'ENTRY'
      )
) TDEST
ON TDEST.ENDZONE = T2.LEGSUM.LS_FROM_ZONE
AND TDEST.LS_DRIVER = T2.LS_DRIVER
AND TDEST.LS_POWER_UNIT = T2.LS_POWER_UNIT
```

I am trying to get a data set from my LEGSUM table that corresponds to the result of my subquery which will then be used to filter more data using IN.

Comment: END_ZONE <> ENDZONE

Comment: How about `SELECT
      TLORDER.END_ZONE,`-> `SELECT
      TLORDER.END_ZONE as ENDZONE,` ?

Comment: geez... thank you... been at it for several hours modifying structure and all it was is a typo!

Comment: @jarlh Comment was what helped you, wasn't it? Jarlh would you like to make an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reconsider the use of a subquery since outer and subquery share same source table, `LYNX.LEGSUM`, at unit level. Consider incorporating a self-join on this same table:

```
SELECT l2.*
FROM
  LYNX.LEGSUM l
LEFT OUTER JOIN LYNX.TLORDER t
  ON l.LS_DLID = t.DETAIL_LINE_ID
INNER JOIN LYNX.LEGSUM l2
  AND l2.LS_FROM_ZONE = t.END_ZONE
  AND l2.LS_DRIVER = l.LS_DRIVER
  AND l2.LS_POWER_UNIT = l.LS_POWER_UNIT

WHERE
  t.ORIGIN = 'PRO8060'
  AND l.LS_ACTUAL_DATE >= '2017-01-01 00:00:00'
  AND l.LS_ACTUAL_DATE < '2018-01-01 00:00:00'
  AND NOT (
    t.CURRENT_STATUS = 'CANCEL'
    OR t.CURRENT_STATUS = 'CANCL'
    OR t.CURRENT_STATUS = 'ENTRY'
  )
```

Comment: The part that would follow is to exclude all the result that does have " TLORDER.ORIGIN ='PRO8060' " To be left only with the difference

Comment: See update with a self join on `LYNX.LEGSUM`. Does that work?

Comment: Works pretty well, getting the same number of reccords, didn't check performance, seem to be negligable over 250k returned reccords but like the structure a lot more then my original one. Now for the tricky part where I need to fit reccords one to one! Thank you for your help @Parfait !

Comment: I'm thinking you do not want to hardcode `t.ORIGIN = 'PRO8060'`. If so, then use an `INNER JOIN` subquery that returns distinct `ORIGIN` from `TLORDER` and then join `t.ORIGIN = subq.ORIGIN`. Of course add `t.ORIGIN` in `SELECT` as indicator to rows.

Comment: like you mentionned, I poste it in another question

Answer (score 0):

You are missing Underscore in the END_ZONE used in ON clause

Comment: Hmm, copying a comment as long as the author has not answered, ..... I am tempted to consider this abusive. But your other history looks genuine.

Comment: This question should actually be closed due to typo as it does not help future readers.